# Regex to cut last one or two digits from string in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data like that:
App2Aa1
Cry10Aa4
Cry2Ac10

I want output like:
App2Aa
Cry10Aa
Cry2Ac

I tried regex

```
data['id'] = data['id'].str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]\d+', r'[a-zA-Z]+[0-9][0-9]\w\w', regex=False)
```

My case is to Cut one or two digits and make record shorter

Comment: How do you decide whether to remove one or two characters? What is the criterion? Why does Cry2Ac10 should become Cry2Ac and not Cry2Ac1?

Comment: If you're trying to use regex, why do you pass `regex=False`?

Comment: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. This is why is use regex= . Cry2Ac10 is name of protein and domains. Cry is first domain 1-2 digits is second domain etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to just strip all trailing digits.  If so, then we can use `str.replace` with the regex pattern `\d+$`:

```py
data["id"] = data["id"].str.replace(r'\d+$', '', regex=True)
```